# Cannot get category and subcategory product data in Laravel using Relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have three tables which i'm using to fetch categories and their related products,

> Categories:

```
id | name | slug | parent_id
```

> Products:

```
id | name | slug | price
```

> Product_categories:

```
id | category_id | product_id
```

I have following menu items generated

```
Mens  
   | Topwear 
     |  Jackets 
     |  Shirts
     |  T-Shirts

Womens
     | Topwear
       |  Kurtis
       |  T-Shirts
```

i'm using following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/top-wear
```

to display top level category products,
but if i add subcategory with top level category

```
http://localhost:8000/top-wear/Jackets
```

i.e. jackets here then i should get only jacket but right now i'm getting all the products in that category, i.e. Jackets, Shirts, T-Shirts.

> Controller Code is :

```
public function show($categorySlug, $subcategorySlug=null)
    {   
        $child_categories=$this->categoryRepository->getchild_catproducts($categorySlug);
        return view('site.pages.category', compact('child_categories'));
    }
```

> Model:

```
public function getchild_catproducts($categorySlug)
{
    $productsLists= Category::with(['products', 'children', 'children.products'])->where('slug',$categorySlug)->get();
    return $productsLists;
}
```

> View:

```
   @foreach($child_categories[0]->children as $cat_prod)
          @foreach($cat_prod->products as $product)
             <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="card list-item bg-white rounded overflow-hidden position-relative shadow-sm">
                   <span class="like-icon"><a class="active" href="#"> <i class="icofont icofont-heart"></i></a></span>
                   <a href="#">
                   <span class="badge badge-success">50% OFF</span>
                   @php ($product_img=$product->images['0']['full']) 
                   <img src="{{  asset('storage/'.$product_img) }}" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></a>
                   <div class="card-body">
                      <h6 class="card-title mb-1"><a href="{{ route('product.show', $product->slug) }}">{{ $product->name }}</a></h6>
                      <div class="stars-rating"><i class="icofont icofont-star active"></i><i class="icofont icofont-star active"></i><i class="icofont icofont-star active"></i><i class="icofont icofont-star active"></i><i class="icofont icofont-star"></i> <span>613</span></div>
                      <p class="mb-0 text-dark">{{ $product->sale_price }} <span class="text-black-50"><del>{{ $product->price }} </del></span></p>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          @endforeach
       @endforeach
```

> Category Model:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function products()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

> Routes:

```
Route::get('/{categorySlug}/{subcategorySlug?}', 'Site\CategoryController@show')->name('category.show');
```

Please help to sort out my issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the data but, what's error is thrown and when (controller vs view) would be helpful

Comment: Issue is, suppose when i click on Men>Topwear, where Top Wear is in my case Parent Category will give all products list which are associated to Jackets, Shirts and T-Shirts, but there is scenario where i want to filter by subcategory also i.e. If i pass category Topwear and subcategory Jackets, then only products related to Jackets must 
only be displayed, but in this case if i am passing jackets it is displaying all the three sub categories (Jackets, Shirts, T-Shirts) product.